# Spark null pointer exception when converting JavaRDD to Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, enums, rdd

I am trying to convert a JavaRDD into a Dataframe like so:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, MyObject> myRdd = ...
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myRdd.values(), MyObject.class)
```

This works fine as long as MyObject doesn't have any enums. However, if I add an enum field, I get a null pointer exception. Currently, my workaround is to change the enums into strings, but I was wondering why Dataframe doesn't support enums.